# H2O's RMSE performance report not consistent

Tags: r, h2o

I'm wondering why `h2o.performance` report is different from the standard definition of `rmse` on the test data. `h2o`'s performance report seems to overstate.

Below is a reprex.

```r
iris_h2o = as.h2o(iris)
parts = h2o.splitFrame(iris_h2o, ratios = c(0.5,0.25), seed = 1)
train = parts[[1]]
valid = parts[[2]]
test = parts[[3]]

x = c('Sepal.Width','Petal.Length','Petal.Width')
y = 'Sepal.Length'
auto_gbm = h2o.automl(x= x,
                      y= y,
                      training_frame = train,
                      validation_frame = valid,
                      nfolds = 0,
                      include_algos = c('GBM'),
                      max_models = 5,
                      seed = 1
                      )
best_gbm = h2o.get_best_model(auto_gbm)
 
h2o.performance(best_gbm, test)
```

The above performance result is

```
H2ORegressionMetrics: gbm

MSE:  0.1152907
RMSE:  0.3395449
MAE:  0.2675279
RMSLE:  0.04744378
Mean Residual Deviance :  0.1152907
```

However, when I generate a prediction on the test dataset and calculate `RMSE` manually, the value diverges a lot.

```r
rmse = function(y, y_predict){
  N = length(y)
  RMSE = sqrt(sum((y-y_predict)^2,na.rm=T)/N)
  return(RMSE)
}

test['predicted'] = h2o.predict(best_gbm, test)

rmse(test['Sepal.Length'], test['predicted'])

[1] 1.890506
```

H2O's performance report on RMSE : 0.33

Manual calculation on RMSE : 1.89

which is more than 5 times bigger. Why am I seeing this inconsistency?

```
H2O cluster version:        3.36.1.4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mistake in your rmse function. The return of `length(y)` is not returning what you think it does. You should use `nrow` to get the number of rows. You can check this with `length(test['Sepal.Length'])`, which will return 1 and not 31 as you expect. Your function should be like this:

```
rmse = function(y, y_predict){
  N = nrow(y)
  RMSE = sqrt(sum((y-y_predict)^2,na.rm=T)/N)
  return(RMSE)
}

rmse(test['Sepal.Length'], test['predicted'])
[1] 0.3395448
```

Comment: With further experiments, I realized that `data_frame$Sepal.Length` results in vector, `H2O.Frame$Sepal.Length` results in `H2O.Frame`, so `length()` does not do what I was trying to achieve.